# FSEventsFramework - Dont watch subdirs

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-foundation, fsevents

I am watching a directory with FSEventsFramework on OSX 10.7+ and I don't want to be notified of changes in subdirectories and it seems to be doing that. Is this normal? Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: What is exactly the use case? Why would you bother receiving more events than you need? Also there can be other ways to achieve your goal, not only FSEvents.

Comment: Thanks @mahaltertin what alternatives to FSEvents are there? I need to watch a directory just for immediate children changes. Reason is if a subdir is removed, we don't get notification on the children of that subdir being removed, so its inconsistent with other OS. I'm making a cross-OS file watching API from js-ctypes.

Comment: Check your other question, I added more details. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal and I didn't find any way to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks mahal, what I'm doing is on callback I'm getting the parent directory of the path and if that path is not in my array of watched paths then I ignore it, a solution that has doesn't prevent overhead (from extra calls that are ignored) but does the trick.